# WordPress 4.9.3, $_COOKIE, and session_start()

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I solved my problem but I don't know why it works. I was hoping someone could shed some light?

I have a WordPress site. If a new user visits the site, they see a generic element on the homepage. When they visit an internal page, a cookie is created. When the user visits the homepage again, they see a customized element based on the cookie.

The problem I was having was that when the user returned to the homepage from an internal page, even though the new cookie was set with the right value, the $COOKIE superglobal was not reset until a refresh was performed. You could naviagte to as many different pages as you'd  like, but still the superglobal was not reset until a literal refresh was performed. This was using both setcookie() and the setting the super global directly.

This was fixed by adding session_start() to the header. I thought session_start() affected the SESSION super global. Why did this solution also affect the COOKIE superglobal?

Comment: Most likely it didn't, not directly - but by [sending different headers regarding caching](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cache-limiter), it influenced how your browser was instructed to check for changes when displaying the same URL again, whereas before you simply got a stale copy presented from the cache.

Comment: That makes sense. I was thinking it had something to do with caching too -- it just seemed odd to me that cookies would be cached as well. Do you know if adding session_start() will have any impact on the site's performance? I was having a hard time finding good documentation on what all the function does.

Comment: Sessions are cookies too (well the SESS ID is anyway), but I agree it was likely caching.  I'm not sure what all session_start does, but if your not having any issues I wouldn't worry about it to much.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @CBroe can you convert your comment to an answer? Tomorrow I will confirm that different caching headers are sent using session_start() and accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why did this solution also affect the COOKIE superglobal?

Most likely it didn't, not directly - but by [sending different headers regarding caching](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cache-limiter), it influenced how your browser was instructed to check for changes when displaying the same URL again, whereas before you simply got a stale copy presented from the cache.

> it just seemed odd to me that cookies would be cached as well

Well not the cookie itself got "cached" - but the document in which you made any output *depending* on the cookie was. You still saw the first version of the page you loaded - the PHP code behind this was not executed again, because the browser did not actually request the URL from the server again.

But when the server sent a response header indicating that this page should not be cached (or that the client you check with the server before displaying the resource again) the first time it was loaded - it caused the browser to make a new request when you returned to the page.

Comment: That's was a very clear explanation. Thank you for your time.